# Getting time in Java

Tags: java, time

How can I get seconds from 1970 in Java?

Comment: Haha, don't see that very often... Ummm, migrate to StackOverflow?  :-D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mean epoch time? You can use

```
long epoch = (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L);
```

that will get the number of seconds since January 1st 1970 UTC time.

this belongs on StackOverflow though, it will be moved there shortly so please don't repost.

Comment: Voting you up for a more complete answer:)

Comment: You should divide by 1000L rather than 1000 to avoid unecessary casting.

Comment: @Adamski haven't used java in a while, I only program now for making personal tasks faster :) Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

`java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()` gives you the time since Jan 1, 1970 in milliseconds.  Just divide by 1000 to get the time in seconds.

Comment: +1 assuming it was posted simultaneously, as it happens all the time